# Discord.py - 'VoiceState' object does not have 'voice_channel' attribute

Tags: python

Making a music bot discord. Code that throws an error:

```
import config
import discord
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
player = {}

@client.event
async def on_ready():
        print('Logged on as BOT!')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
    print("Joined channel" + str(voice_channel))
```

I tried to change the value voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel на
voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

When using the command .join, in the console issues:

```
Ignoring exception in command join:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\diram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 79, in wrapped
        ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
      File "music.py", line 15, in join
        voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\diram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 863, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\diram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\diram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 88, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel` instead. It is `.channel`, not `.voice_channel`, as per the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html.